# MySQL Suma y Ordenación de valores por campo relacionado

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo dos tablas:

```html
**ventas_cab**
   id    Base  Comensales  
------  ------  ------------
     1   26.80             2
     2   29.14             5
     3   45.07             3
     4   20.65             3
     5   12.20             2
     6   26.52             1
     7   29.60             4
     8   53.03             1
     9    7.50             3
    10  -20.65             5
```

```html
**ventas_lin**
    id  ventas_cab_id    Base  Unidades  CodProd  
------  -------------  ------  --------  ----------------
     1              1    4.85      1.00  01002           
     2              1    4.60      1.00  01007           
     3              1    5.90      1.00  03210           
     4              1    5.95      1.00  05502           
     5              1    1.65      1.00  07203           
     6              1    1.65      1.00  07204           
     7              1    2.20      2.00  09001           
     8              2   12.34      2.00  00001           
     9              2    0.00      2.00  07108           
    10              2    0.00      2.00  06101           
    11              2    0.00      2.00  04003           
    12              2    4.60      1.00  01007           
    13              2    6.75      1.00  04009           
    14              2    3.85      1.00  06107           
    15              2    1.60      1.00  07107           
    16              3    6.17      1.00  00001           
    17              3    0.00      1.00  07108           
    18              3    0.00      1.00  03003           
    19              3    7.15      1.00  04601           
    20              3    5.50      1.00  04702           
    21              3    5.80      1.00  06001           
    22              3    5.25      1.00  07001           
    23              3    3.20      2.00  07104           
    24              3    7.70      2.00  08002           
    25              3    3.20      1.00  08003           
    26              3    1.10      1.00  09002           
    27              4    5.90      1.00  04003           
    28              4    4.25      1.00  06005           
    29              4    2.50      1.00  06101           
    30              4    6.00      1.00  07502           
    31              4    2.00      2.00  08010           
    32              5    4.60      1.00  01007           
    33              5    4.85      1.00  03002           
    34              5    1.65      1.00  07202           
    35              5    1.10      1.00  09001           
    36              6    6.17      1.00  00001           
    37              6    0.00      1.00  07102           
    38              6    0.00      1.00  04003           
    39              6    4.85      1.00  01006           
    40              6    5.30      1.00  03050           
    41              6    5.85      1.00  04013           
    42              6    1.60      1.00  07106           
    43              6    1.65      1.00  07202           
    44              6    1.10      1.00  09001           
    45              6    0.00      1.00  25001           
    46              7    6.50      1.00  03603           
    47              7   13.40      1.00  05021           
    48              7    4.25      1.00  06005           
    49              7    1.60      1.00  07105           
    50              7    1.65      1.00  07202           
    51              7    1.10      1.00  09001           
    52              7    0.00      1.00  25006           
    53              7    1.10      1.00  09001           
    54              7    0.00      1.00  25006           
    55              8    5.00      1.00  01003           
    56              8    1.45      1.00  07010           
    57              8    1.10      1.00  09001           
    58              8    1.10      1.00  09001           
    59              8    0.95      1.00  07102           
    60              8    4.10      1.00  01001           
    61              8    4.10      1.00  01001           
    62              8    6.00      1.00  03503           
    63              8    6.00      1.00  03503           
    64              8    1.10      1.00  09002           
    65              8    1.10      1.00  09018           
    66              8   21.03      3.00  20016           
    67              8    0.00      1.00  07101           
    68              8    0.00      1.00  07102           
    69              8    0.00      1.00  01001           
    70              8    0.00      1.00  03503           
    71              9    5.90      1.00  03210           
    72              9    1.60      1.00  07105           
    73             10   -5.90     -1.00  04003           
    74             10   -4.25     -1.00  06005           
    75             10   -2.50     -1.00  06101           
    76             10   -6.00     -1.00  07502           
    77             10   -2.00     -2.00  08010
```

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta SQL que sume la base y los comensales de **ventas_cab** y que me agrupe y ordene por código de producto que está en **ventas_lin**, incluso, si es posible, que me de suma de Unidades vendidas de cada producto. El resultado es que no me da la suma de Comensales.

La consulta que estoy crea

```html
SELECT
  X,
  D1,
  SUM(ventas_cab.Comensales) AS D2,
  D3
FROM usr_g_ventas_cab AS ventas_cab
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT_WS(" - ",ventas_lin.CodigoProducto,ventas_lin.DescProducto),"") AS X, ventas_cab_id, SUM(ventas_lin.Base) AS D1, SUM(ventas_lin.Unidades) AS D3 
      FROM usr_g_ventas_lin AS ventas_lin 
      GROUP BY ventas_lin.CodigoProducto
      ORDER BY D1 DESC) AS ventas_lin 
  ON ventas_lin.ventas_cab_id = ventas_cab.id 
WHERE ventas_cab.id < 11
GROUP BY X
ORDER BY D1 DESC, D2 DESC;
```

RESULTADO

```html
X                           D1  D2          D3  
----------------------  ------  ------  --------
00001 - Menú del día     24.68  5           4.00
20016                    21.03  1           3.00
01007 - Cardhu           13.80  2           3.00
05021                    13.40  4           1.00
03503                    12.00  1           3.00
03210                    11.80  2           2.00
09001                     8.80  2           8.00
01001 - J&B               8.20  1           3.00
08002                     7.70  3           2.00
04601                     7.15  3           1.00
04009                     6.75  5           1.00
03603                     6.50  4           1.00
05502                     5.95  2           1.00
```

Como debo hacer la suma y el left join para que pueda ver en una sola linea las tres o cuatro sumas.

Gracias.

Comment: A que te refieres con sumar la base con los comensales? es decir que en el ventas_cab de id = 1 te sume 26.80 + 2? y bajo que codigo te lo ordena si hay varios?

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es que coloques la data que tienen tus tablas originales usr_g_ventas_lin y usr_g_ventas_cab, e indicar el resultado que esperas. Creo que la consulta actual está muy enmarañada y podría simplificarse mas sin necesidad de tanta sub consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías tratar de trabajar directamente con las tablas originales y sacar las sumas en tu `select`, así (modifique el nombre de algunos campos, y trabajé con la data de las subconsultas que posteaste pero que parecen ser similares a las tablas originales):

```
SELECT
  ventas_lin.codprod as 'CODIGO',
  sum(ventas_lin.base) as D1,
  sum(ventas_cab.comensales) AS D2,
  sum(ventas_lin.unidades) as D3
FROM ventas_cab
  LEFT JOIN  ventas_lin
  ON ventas_lin.ventas_cab_id = ventas_cab.identificador 
WHERE ventas_cab.identificador < 11
GROUP BY ventas_lin.codprod
ORDER BY D1 DESC, D2 DESC
```

El resultado:

```
CODIGO          D1                                                                                    D2          D3                                                                                    
--------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
00001           24.68                                                                                 9           4.0                                                                                   
20016           21.03                                                                                 1           3.0                                                                                   
1007            13.799999999999999                                                                    9           3.0                                                                                   
5021            13.4                                                                                  4           1.0                                                                                   
3503            12.0                                                                                  3           3.0                                                                                   
3210            11.8                                                                                  5           2.0                                                                                   
9001            8.799999999999999                                                                     15          8.0                                                                                   
1001            8.2                                                                                   3           3.0                                                                                   
8002            7.7                                                                                   3           2.0                                                                                   
4601            7.15                                                                                  3           1.0                                                                                   
4009            6.75                                                                                  5           1.0                                                                                   
3603            6.5                                                                                   4           1.0                                                                                   
5502            5.95                                                                                  2           1.0                                                                                   
4013            5.85                                                                                  1           1.0                                                                                   
6001            5.8                                                                                   3           1.0                                                                                   
4702            5.5                                                                                   3           1.0                                                                                   
3050            5.3                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
7001            5.25                                                                                  3           1.0                                                                                   
1003            5.0                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
7202            4.949999999999999                                                                     7           3.0                                                                                   
1002            4.85                                                                                  2           1.0                                                                                   
3002            4.85                                                                                  2           1.0                                                                                   
1006            4.85                                                                                  1           1.0                                                                                   
6005            4.25                                                                                  12          1.0                                                                                   
6107            3.85                                                                                  5           1.0                                                                                   
7105            3.2                                                                                   7           2.0                                                                                   
8003            3.2                                                                                   3           1.0                                                                                   
7104            3.2                                                                                   3           2.0                                                                                   
9002            2.2                                                                                   4           2.0                                                                                   
7203            1.65                                                                                  2           1.0                                                                                   
7204            1.65                                                                                  2           1.0                                                                                   
7107            1.6                                                                                   5           1.0                                                                                   
7106            1.6                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
7010            1.45                                                                                  1           1.0                                                                                   
9018            1.1                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
7102            0.95                                                                                  3           3.0                                                                                   
4003            0.0                                                                                   14          3.0                                                                                   
6101            0.0                                                                                   13          2.0                                                                                   
7502            0.0                                                                                   8           0.0                                                                                   
8010            0.0                                                                                   8           0.0                                                                                   
7108            0.0                                                                                   8           3.0                                                                                   
25006           0.0                                                                                   8           2.0                                                                                   
3003            0.0                                                                                   3           1.0                                                                                   
7101            0.0                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
25001           0.0                                                                                   1           1.0                                                                                   
(45 rows)Execution time: 0.024 seconds
```

Como observaciones:

1. La condición del where está de más si sabes que el id no llega a 11
2. Tratar de utilizar subconsultas solo cuando son completamente
   necesarios.
3. Utilizar los alias apropiadamente y con nombres descriptivos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porqué, siendo ésta mi primera opción, acumulaba los totales por cada línea de detalle y me multiplicaba los totales. Supongo que la base que cogía era la de ventas_cab en lugar de ventas_lin y eso hacia que se sumara el total por cada linea de producto.

Gracias.